# Extract a string from textfile using JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a substring from a file with Javascript Regex. Here is a slice from the file :

```
Version=2

Format=jpg

Size=1280x960

Date=2013/05/08

Time=23:49:40

Value=250000
```

I want to extract only `Version` and `Value` from the text file.
I tried extracting the Version using this but it doesn't return anything.

```
$('.Content').html().match(/^Version\:(.*)$/g);
```

`$('.Content').html()` contains the whole text file.

Comment: Because you have `:` in place of `=`?

Comment: $('.imageContent').html().match(/^Version\=(.*)$/g); is returning null too

Comment: Remove the anchors.. `$('.Content').html().match(/Version=(.*)/g);`

Comment: it works. how can I append the other results like I want value and version both . can I append those and then display them separated by new line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the anchors or use `m` flag:

```
$('.Content').html().match(/Version=(.*)/g);
```

Or

```
$('.Content').html().match(/^Version=(.*)$/gm);
```

**Edit:** For capturing Value and Version you can do the following:

```
$('.Content').html().match(/Version=(.*)|Value=(.*)/g);
```

You will get Version in `$1` and Value in `$2`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rL7dX9/4)

Comment: Why are you using `g` flag?

Comment: @naomik Because OP has many `Version`'s to match... In his first line he said `Here is a slice from the file` :)

Comment: yes you are right Karthik :) is there any chance I can merge all the result and then display them together ?

Comment: @PSDebugger no sure what you mean by merging all results.. check the update :)

Comment: yes this works and last thing how can I separate each of them by a new line.

Comment: @PSDebugger can you show some example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It returns nothing because you're using `:` in your regex instead of `=`.

Comment: $('.imageContent').html().match(/^Version\=(.*)$/g); is returning null too

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the `Version`, there's plenty of other answers here.

If you need to parse the entire file, maybe use something like this

```
var re = /^(\w+)=(.*)$/gm;
var result = {};
var match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  result[match[1]] = match[2];
}

console.log(result.Version);
//=> "2"

console.log(result.Value);
//=> "250000"

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
// {
//   "Version": "2",
//   "Format": "jpg",
//   "Size": "1280x960",
//   "Date": "2013/05/08",
//   "Time": "23:49:40",
//   "Value": "250000"
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern should be: (replace `:` by `=` and remove `$` and `g` at the end)

```
/^Version=(.*)/
```

Comment: Why are you using `g` flag?

Comment: He used that flag. I did not know about his intention so I kept it there.

Comment: Well he told you his intention was to capture the value after `Version`.

Comment: Yes, he will be able to do this with the second capture group. The `g` does not make any difference in this case.

Comment: If it makes no difference, then why is it there? Write less code™

Comment: Agreed. Updated my answer

Comment: I am getting the result as ["DataSize=1280x960","Magnification=0", "MicronMarker=200", "PixelSize=0.396875"] but I want to display everything in a new line.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/(Version|Value)=(.*)/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `:` for `=` and add `m` flag.

```
^(?:Version|Value)=(.*)$/gm
```

Demo:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var re = /^(?:Version|Value)=(.*)$/gm; 
  var str = $('.Content').html();
  var m;
  var result = "";
 
  while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
      if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
          re.lastIndex++;
      }
    result += m[1] + ", ";
    
}
  $('#result').text(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Content">
Version=2

Format=jpg

Size=1280x960

Date=2013/05/08

Time=23:49:40

Value=250000
</div>
<br>
<div id="result">test</div>
```